# left join linq query in FF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Documents d
LEFT JOIN 
Invoices
ON (i.invoicedocumentid = d.id or i.jobsheetdocumentid = d.id)
INNER JOIN
PurchaseOrders PO ON i.poid = PO.id
LEFT JOIN
HelpDeskFaults f
ON f.id = PO.helpDeskFaultId
LEFT JOIN stores s
ON s.id = f.storeid
WHERE s.name = 'Linden Drive'
OR d.id in (
   SELECT u.id as 'docid'
   FROM documents u
   INNER JOIN stores s
   ON u.storeid = s.id
   WHERE s.name = 'Linden Drive'
)
ORDER BY d.Id
```

So far my linq query looks like this:

```
var documents = from doc in context.Documents
            from invoice in context.Invoices
            join po in context.PurchaseOrders on invoice.PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderId equals po.PurchaseOrderId
            join hdf in context.HelpDeskFaults on po.HelpdeskFaultId equals hdf.ID into hdfpo
            from hs in hdfpo.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join store in context.Stores on hs.StoreID equals store.ID into hsstore
            from hss in hsstore.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where hss.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.StoreName) && (invoice.InvoiceDocumentId == doc.ID || invoice.JobSheetInvoiceId == doc.ID)
            select doc;
```

But the sql that is produced is nothing like what I expected.

Can anyone give me any pointers of how to improve my linq query.

Comment: Does it return the correct results in a timely manner?  Because if it does I wouldn't worry too much about the SQL that is produced by EF.

Comment: Also you can simply those left joins by using navigation properties like `from hs in po.HelpdeskFaults.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: no it for not return any results.  im not in work now but the sql is quite far removed.  I'm confused about the left join syntax

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would translate your SQL query into

```
var results = 
    (from doc in context.Documents
     from invoice in (
         from inv in context.Invoices 
         where inv.InvoiceDocumentId == doc.ID || inv.JobSheetInvoiceId == doc.ID
         select inv).DefaultIfEmpty()
     from hs in invoice.PurchaseOrder.HelpDeskFaults.DefaultIfEmpty()
     from hss in hs.Stores.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where hss.Name == "Linden Drive" || doc.Store.Name == "Linden Drive"
     order by doc.ID
     select new 
     {
         Document = doc,
         Invoice = invoice,
         invoice.PurchaseOrder,
         HelpDeskFault = hs,
         Store = hss,
     }).Distinct();
```

I included that anonymous class of the 5 entities because your SQL is using `Select *`.  I would recommend changing it to only return the minimum required set of fields.